# xarray grib file - Error of shape extracting data

Tags: python-xarray, grib, cfgrib

I downloaded CERRA grib data of 173 Go. Here is the informations of the grib2 file :
[image]

By this code i try to get ws variables for all timestamp in particular lat,lon:

```
lat = 47 
lon = 4.9 
abslat = np.abs(ds.latitude-lat) 
abslon = np.abs(ds.longitude-lon) 
c = np.maximum(abslon, abslat) 
([xloc], [yloc]) = np.where(c == np.min(c)) 
dfb = ds.sel(x=yloc, y=xloc,heightAboveGround=100)
```

The informations of the new xarray.Dataset is :
[image]

Finally, i want to get all values of variable ws :

```
dfb.to_dataframe()
```

It should return a dataframe of 18984 value for each time. Unfornately, I have this error :
[image]

For me, it's not the expected shape of the dataframe. I tried to limit the number of ws value by :

```
dfb.ws[:100].to_dataframe()
```

And it returns as expected :
[image]

Comment: it appears that i can't get the value when the index is >= 235 :' OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'